# Using Slim Framework on Raspberry pi with Apache2

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to create a small API to play around with using the Slim Framework and a raspberry pi with Apache2 installed.
Right now I can reach the raspberry over the internet so ports 80 and 22 are open and I can view html/php files that I upload to it however the slim API that I made wont work unless i run it with php -S 0.0.0.0:8080 -t public public/index.php in the console.

My .htaccess file looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

My index.php looks like this:

```
<?php
use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$app = new \Slim\App;
$app->get('/hello', function (Request $request, Response $response) {
    header("Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8");    

    $author = "Albert Einstein";
    $wiki_request_json = file_get_contents("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=". urlencode($author) . "&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&format=json&indexpageids");
    $wiki_request_decoded = json_decode($wiki_request_json);
    $wiki_page_id = $wiki_request_decoded->query->pageids[0];
    $wiki_page_id = (int)$wiki_page_id;
    $star = '*';

    return json_encode($wiki_request_decoded->query->pages->$wiki_page_id->revisions[0]->$star);
});
$app->run();
```

And I can not get it to work. So far I've activated mod_rewrite with sudo a2enmod rewrite. I've also changed my apache2.conf and added

```
<Directory /var/www/slimapi/public/>
AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

and in the public folder i have my .htaccess file and index.php file. 
I also opened the etc/apache2/sites-available/default file and changed the first two AllowOverride to All but still nothing and now I'm out of ideas. Anyone done something similar before?

Comment: Have you pointed the DocumentRoot at `/var/www/slimapi/public/`?

Comment: If I go into the etc/apache2/sites-available/default and change the DocumentRoot to /var/www/slimapi/public/ everything on the server goes offline and the API still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. The required path was wrong so it couldn't find it, changed it to

```
require __DIR__.'../../vendor/autoload.php';
```

and it started working like a charm